# Slow filling toilet tank after new valve kit installation

Tags: toilet

I did a new installation of Fluidmaster (400ARHRK) on both fill valve and flush valve. Now the refill after flushing is much slower than before (took about 2 minutes).

I read the post and reply of [why my toilet fill too slow](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/75412/why-is-my-toilet-tank-filling-too-slowly), but it didn't seem to address my issue. I have opened the cap and water come out of it fine (probably not long as suggested 15 seconds). Some has suggested there is a flow restrictor inside the shank that I can pull out - I am not sure that is the root cause. Earlier I did another one with 400CR, just the fill, it didn't have this issue.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: the "fill valve" refers to the part that come with the all-in-one fluidmaster repair kit, not the shutoff at the wall.

Comment: Double check for the following: defective/obstructed stop-valve at wall, kinked flex connector, debris in fill valve/gaskets.

Answer (score 1):

My toilet would require 15 minutes to refill. I found what looks to be a restrictor (rubber screw like plug) inside the lower water inlet tube. I removed it and the toilet fills quickly as intended. Although I can't find any source that identifies this part or its intended function.